# Android ICS connection via 3G getting 403 response but OK via Wifi

Tags: android, wifi, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 3g, http-status-code-403

I'm getting a strange issue on Android ICS, I have the following code to stablish a connection to read an xml file:

```
// previous code......

URL url = new URL("https://urltomyxmlfile.com/xmlfile");
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
XML_handler myXML_handler = new XML_handler();
xr.setContentHandler(myXML_handler);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
connection.setReadTimeout(25000);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
xr.parse(new InputSource(input));

//more code....
```

This code works properly in all android versions both wifi and 3G but in Android ICS only works with wifi, on a 3G connection I'm getting a 403 response.

I can't figure the origin of this issue, Am I not properly configuring the connection? Is there any new restriction in Android ICS? problems with https?

Extra info: this code is not running in the UI-thread

Thanks for your help!

New Extra info: I have discovered that only Samsung Galaxy SII users are experiencing the issue.

Comment: Maybe your mobile network gateway IP is blocked. Did you try to use the mobile network with your computer?

Comment: Actually I'm not getting this error because I'm not using a SG-SII with Android ICS, my app users and beta testers are reporting me the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got the answer!!!, it was not code related.

Spanish carrier ORANGE is selling terminals and sending OTA updates with a wrong APN configuration. Please find pasted below the correct APN configuration to avoid this issue for the main Spanish Carriers (Vodafone, Movistar, Orange, Yoigo and Simyo)

VODAFONE ES-INTERNET

Nombre: Vodafone ES 
APN: airtelwap.es
Proxy: No establecido
Puerto: No establecido
Nombre de Usuario: wap@wap
Contraseña: wap125
Servidor: No establecido
MMSC: null
Proxy MMS: No establecido
Puerto MMS: No establecido
MCC: 214
MNC: 01
Tipo de APN: default

MOVISTAR -INTERNET

Nombre: Movistar
APN: telefonica.es
Proxy: 10.138.255.133
Puerto: 8080
Nombre de Usuario: telefonica
Contraseña: telefonica
Servidor: No establecido
MMSC: No establecido
Proxy MMS: No establecido
Puerto MMS: No establecido
Código País del Móvil (MCC): 214
Código de Red Móvil (MNC): 07
Autentificación: No establecido
Tipo de APN: internet

ORANGE -INTERNET

Nombre: Orange Internet
APN: internet
Proxy: No establecido
Puerto: No establecido
Nombre de Usuario: cliente
Contraseña: amena
Servidor: 62.36.225.150
MMSC: No establecido
Proxy MMS: No establecido
Puerto MMS: No establecido
MCC: 214
MNC: 03
Tipo de APN: default

YOIGO-INTERNET

Nombre: Yoigo
APN: internet
Proxy: 10.08.00.36
Puerto: 8080
MMSC:
Proxy MMS:
Puerto MMS:
MCC: 214
MNC: 04
Tipo de autentificacion: PAP
Tipo de APN: Internet

SIMYO -INTERNET

Nombre: SimyoInternet
APN:gprs-service.com
Proxy: No establecido
Puerto: No establecido
Nombre de Usuario: No establecido
Contraseña: No establecido
Servidor: No establecido
MMSC: No establecido
Proxy MMS: No establecido
Puerto MMS: No establecido
MCC: 214
MNC: 19
Tipo de APN: default

Comment: You saved my life. I tried EVERYTHING, we spent almost 4 full work days to determine why the app was running everywhere except on my Nexus 4. Now I want to kill somebody.